# Shell-Script: Get cURL error, if wrong user

Tags: shell, curl, error-handling

My shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -f -T /home/skript_1.txt -u XXX:XXXXXXX! -k http://192.168.0.100/home/test.txt
res=$?
if test "$res" != 0; then
   echo "the curl command failed with: $res"
else
   echo "Success $res"
fi
```

I use this to ulpad a file...

Now my problem is, that I can't get all errors.
As an example if I enter a wrong URL (the right URL would be http://192.168.0.100:5005/home/test.txt), the upload fails, but the exit code still is 0.

Here is the output with a wrong URL:

```
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
Success 0
```

How can I get those errors as well?

I also tried the same thing with cURL and and ftp target, there it works with all errors.

Comment: I never used `-f`. Based on your description, it is worth to extract the HTTP status from the output with `serverResponse=$(curl -f ...)
...
...
if [ ! -z $(printf '%s\n' "${serverResponse}" | sed -n 's/^.*title.\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\) .*$/\1/gp' ] ; then printf "Failure\n"; fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-w 'http_code %{http_code}'` will make `curl` add the HTTP status code at the end of the output.

Maybe you could go for this new version, which I only partially tested:

```
#!/bin/bash
serverResponse=$(curl -f -w 'http_code %{http_code}' -T /home/skript_1.txt -u XXX:XXXXXXX! -k http://192.168.0.100/home/test.txt)
res=$?
if test "$res" != 0; then
   printf "the curl command failed with: %s\n" "${res}"
else
   http_code="${serverResponse##*http_code }"
   if [[ ! -z "${http_code}" && "${http_code}" -ne 200 ]] ; then
     printf "Server sent back this http status: %s\n" "${http_code}"
   else
     printf "Success %s\n" "${res}"
   fi
fi
```